# What should I do if my "Region" is not in the list while creating SQL database in Microsoft Azure Portal?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, region

I have purchased "Pay-As-You-Go" plan in Azure for my website hosting. I am from Bosnia and Herzegovina country which is located in Southern Europe Region. While creating database in windows azure, we have to select the Region from the drop down list. That drop down list doesn't contain "Southern Europe" region in the list. In this case, which Region I should select from the list? OR how should I proceed to create the database?

Comment: Your service will work fine whichever location you choose, but may work better for those who are closer closer to the region you select, so in your case you should select 'West Europe' region as it's the closest location to Bosnia and Herzegovina they have available.

Comment: This question should be posted to ServerFault.

Answer (score 2):

I guess that you're looking for the region nearest your location.  Based upon that assumption, you should select West Europe because the data centre is located in The Netherlands.  North Europe is located in Ireland.

Check this page to find all the data centres locations: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/regions/